# How to convert input stdin to list data structure in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, stdin

I have a stdin data in this format:
100 
85 92 
292 42
88 33
500
350 36
800 45
0

I want something like this [[100, [85, 92], [292, 42], [88, 33]], [500, [350, 36], [800, 45], [0]]

Comment: why is 100 and 500 not in list and 0 in list?

Comment: Where are you stuck?  For example, `for line in sys.stdin:` is how to read from lines from the standard input stream.

Comment: First of all convert / change your stdin data formate as an array and try yourself, and if you are stuck then share your efforts and ask for a solution where you stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following (I have tested) should do it:

```
lst = []
sublst = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    lineLst = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
    if len(lineLst) == 1:
        if sublst: lst.append(sublst)
        sublst = lineLst
    else:
        sublst.append(lineLst)
    
if sublst[0] == 0: lst.append(sublst)
```